# Change image with href in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="#" id=BigSwatch><img src="addtocart.png" onclick="SwapLink('ekhle.html');"
 onClick=display('pleasewait.png') /></a>
```

In this coding, I want change image and change href also.
here when user click on **addtocart.png** image, I want to change image to **pleasewait.png** and when user click on **pleasewait.png** image, I want to change href like "**url2.html**", but when i apply my coding image changed but **url2.html** page also redirect directly.

Comment: Now what are these functions? This isn't the right way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id=BigSwatch><img id="test" src="addtocart.png" onclick="SwapLink('ekhle.html');"
 onClick=display('pleasewait.png') /></a>
```

**Script**

```
$('#BigSwatch').on({
    'click': function(){
        $('#test').attr('src','pleasewait.png');
        $('#BigSwatch').attr('href','url2.html');
    }
});
```

Comment: it is directly redirect my page from index.html to other.html

Comment: i don't want it. i want only change image and when user click on second image url redirect to other.html page

Comment: http://merchworld.eu/products/ane-brun/3094/birds-grey# , here you can see example of this, when i select the color image changed and and href of image also change. Please help

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id=BigSwatch><img src="addtocart.png" /></a>
```

**in JS**

```
 $("#BigSwatch").on("click","img",function(){
    $(this).attr("src","pleasewait.png");// here your image path will set
    $(this).closest("#BigSwatch").attr("href","ekhle.html");


    });
```

Comment: this not work as i want friend, http://merchworld.eu/products/ane-brun/3094/birds-grey#, here you can see the example of this type when you select size and color, image changed and href also change

Answer (score 0):

The better way is you can put an anchor with background image. You can follow the simple process -

1. Keep an anchor with background image "addToCart.png" and with class "addToCart"
2. On click change the class to "pleasewait" which will change the background-image to "pleasewait.png"
3. On Click write a function to check, if it has class "addToCart" then prevent default redirection else go to "url2.html".

**HTML:**

```
<a href="url2.html" id="BigSwatch" class="addToCart"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.addToCart {
    background-image:url('images/addToCart.png');
    display:block;
    /* Define width and height */
}
.pleaseWait {
    background-image:url('images/pleaseWait.png');
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#BigSwatch').click(function(e){
   if($(this).hasClass('addToCart')) {
      $(this).removeClass('addToCart').addClass('pleaseWait');
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

I Hope this would work fine.

Comment: it is directly redirect to page url2.html. i want only change image and hen i click on pleasewait.png image then page url2.html open

Comment: Yes, since initially it has class 'addToCart' the default redirect will be prevented due to e.preventDefault(). And then on next click it will use the href URL.

Comment: You may refer to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d4L4K/
Only difference is I am changing color in place of image and opening that url in new tab as its in fiddle.

Comment: but this not work then i apply this on my pc   java script is <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$('#BigSwatch').click(function(e){
   if($(this).hasClass('addToCart')) {
      $(this).removeClass('addToCart').addClass('pleaseWait');
      e.preventDefault("www.google.com");
   }
});
</script>

Comment: an css is like <style>
#BigSwatch{
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.addToCart {
    background-color:red;
}
.pleaseWait {
   background-color:green;
}
</style>

Comment: and html is <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="BigSwatch" class="addToCart"></a> but this is work. this directly redirect to google

Comment: @user2930603: Please check your code. 1. Put the javascript inside $(document).ready(function(){ // put that code here});

2. Simply e.preventDefault(); will work.
3. CSS is fine, depends where have you put that CSS.
4. Remove semicolon there and you can ignore target="_blank".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your **HTML mark up only** like this

```
<a href="#" id=BigSwatch onClick="this.href='ekhle.html'">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png" 
 onClick="this.src='https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png'; this.parent.href='ekhle.html'" />
</a>
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktYy6/)

I have used images from google. :)

Comment: yes this is work but first i want change only image then redirect to other page please help

Comment: @user2930603 will you be clicking again or in the same click

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function switchHref(){
info=document.getElementById("hr");
info1=document.getElementById("link");
if(info.src.match("pleasewait.png")){
    window.location="irl.html";
}
else{
    info.src="pleasewait.png";
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="addtocart.png" id="hr" onclick="switchHref()"        
width="100" height="100"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi friend
i want add a radio button above for select size. Is this possible that when i click on addtocart.png image, first it show "please select size" and after select radio button further processing addtocart.png change to plesewait.png and href also.

Comment: r u trying to select size of an image before it goes to second image ??

Comment: no.
you can see example of this at http://merchworld.eu/products/ane-brun/3094/birds-grey here when we select size of t-shirt then add tocart button change. i want this. please help , i know you can o this. please

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function switchHref(){
info=document.getElementById("hr");
info1=document.getElementById("link");
doc=document.getElementById("rad");
if(doc.checked==true){
    info.src="pleasewait.png";
}
if(info.src.match("pleasewait.png")){
    window.location="url.html";
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="addtocart.png" id="hr" width="100"   
height="100"/>
<input type="radio" id="rad"  
onChange="switchHref()" />Click
</body>
</html>
```